# InDesign: How to make sure that new chapter are on the right side?

Tags: adobe-indesign, book

I designed a book in InDesign. How can I make sure that every new chapter is starting on the right side before going to print?

Below, page 7 and 19 are new chapter.
Page 2 is the book title page. Similar when we open a book the first page is usually the book title.

[image]

Is the only way to verify it is to print it or can I do something in InDesign so that every new chapter are on the right?

[image]

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re asking here exactly. You can see what’s left and what’s right in InDesign. I don’t see what the print dialogue has to do with this. Your title page is currently on a left page – the way to get it to a right page is simply to move it there, or to use a paragraph style which is set to start on next odd page… Am I missing something in the question here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the paragraph style 'Keep Options' to every chapter first paragraph to start paragraph 'On Next Odd Page'.

[image]